# Как объединить два фильтра в один

Tags: django

Собственно сам вопрос в заголовке
Помогите объединить два данных фильтра в один

> args['posts_category'] =
> Post.objects.filter(rubrics__parent__slug=posts_category)#фильтрует по
> главным категориям
>
> args['posts_category2'] =
> Post.objects.filter(rubrics=get_object_or_404(Category,
> slug=posts_category))#фильтрует по подкатегориям

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы выбрать записи из таблицы, которые соответствуют хотя бы одному из условий, нужно воспользоваться [объектом Q](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q)

```
args['posts_category'] = Post.objects.filter(Q(rubrics__parent__slug=posts_category) |
    Q(rubrics=get_object_or_404(Category, slug=posts_category)))
```